# «while read» construction broke ZSH (oh-my-zsh)

Tags: macos, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I use Zsh with oh-my-zsh,

following code broke zsh:

```
find ... | while read path                                                                                                                     
do
    echo "dedug «${path}»"
done
```

Then all not builtin scripts and functions are broken

```
❯ invntrm $ which whois
whois not found

❯ invntrm $ which man
man not found

...
```

Restart fix problem until i run the command again.

My setup is almost stock, i use some omz plugins:

```
      git                 #·
      command-not-found   #·
      coffee              #·
      encode64            #·
      httpie              #·
      node                #·
      npm                 #·
      cp                  # cp with progress bar (rsync)
      extract             # 'x' alias - swiss knife for archive extracting
      safe-paste          # No execute immidiately every line # No compatible with zsh-autosuggestions :(
      fasd                # https://github.com/clvv/fasd - command-line productivity booster, offers quick access to files and directories
      brew                #·
      osx                 # https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Plugins#osx
      copyfile            # copies selected file content to clipboard
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `PATH` environmental variable is definitely empty/broken. It contains all folders from where you use binaries, such as `echo`, `man`, `grep`, `ffmpeg` etc.

Check it before and after the script: `echo "$PATH"`.
On my *oh-my-zsh* everything works clearly (but I use different configuration, of course).

You should raise an issue on [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh.git) that one of their plugins annuls `PATH`.

Which one - you should find out. You can try to enable-disable them, and then check when does the `PATH` change in the source code of the wrong plugin.

You can also update *oh-my-zsh*. Go to it's folder and write `git pull`.

Comment: i figured out today the problem.

Comment: `$path` and `$PATH` are equal For Zsh... Fail

Comment: theoden, do you know, how to switch this zsh behaviour (ignoring variable names case)?

Comment: It's not that `zsh` is ignoring case; `path` and `PATH` are two separate names, but `path` is synchronized with `PATH`. Where `PATH` is a colon-delimited list of directory names, `path` is an array with each directory in `PATH` as a distinct element.

Comment: @Atombit, I suppose that there's no way you can change that. If I needed to export my variable, I'd think of a namespace like `SID_` and make all my variables belonging to it: `$SID_PATH`, or `SID_PYTHON`, or whatever.

Comment: chepner, could you post as answer?

Answer (score -1):

Do not name some temp variables as `path` in Zsh.